# sqoop from MySQL where the data contains carriage returns

Tags: mysql, hive, sqoop

I have a MySQL table where some of the values in a varchar column end with '^M' (i.e. carriage return or '\r') while others do not. The MySQL database is part of a production environment that I do not control, and so I'm unable to remove the trailing carriage returns with a simple `update mytable set mycol = trim(mycol);`.

When I `sqoop` the MySQL table to my cluster, I notice that the records with carriage return end up misaligned resulting in some strange query results. The sqoop (v 1.4.4) command looks like this:

```
sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:mysql://myhost:3306/mydb
    --username myuser
    --password mypass
    --table mytable
    --target-dir user/hive/warehouse/mydb.db/mytable
    --hive-import
    --hive-table mydb.mytable
    --hive-overwrite -m 1
```

Q) Is it possible to `sqoop` data that contains some carriage returns directly from MySQL without having some sort of intermediate step to remove the carriage returns?

The ideal workflow would be a simple `sqoop` command scheduled by `oozie`. Staging the data and stripping out `\r` with sed (or whatever) seems like a kludge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was in the manual (http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopUserGuide.html). I needed to add the following argument to my `sqoop` statement:

```
--hive-drop-import-delims
```